# How to get permission AWS ec2 server to allow to save files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, terminal, jupyter-notebook

I am running an Amazon Web Service ec2 Amazon Linux AMI as these tutorials explain it:

- https://www.guru99.com/jupyter-notebook-tutorial.html#5 - server configuration
- https://www.guru99.com/pyspark-tutorial.html  -  actual project I am doing
- I have gotten an error when I have tried to get the csv file from the URL and open it as in the project.
- So I have copied the file up to the aws ec2 main folder from my local machine.
- Than I have tried to copy the file from the main servr directory to the jupiter notebook's folder
- it have given me permission an error:

```
cp: cannot create regular file ‘work/adult_data.csv’: Permission denied
```

- to solve this I have run the following 2 commands:

```
[ec2-user]$ sudo chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user work
[ec2-user]$ sudo chmod -R 755 work
```

- Than I could copy the files in to the Jupiter notebook's folder
- but from this point I can't do savings with the Jupiter notebooks folder, I also can't rename the csv file I have copied there. the error message says the following:

```
Permission denied: folder/jupiterfilename.ipynb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a sudo su -
After you login on the the ec2 server , run below command

sudo su -

This will give you root permissions

Comment: This is very nice, but does not solves my problem to be able to save my Jupiter notebook.

Comment: Could you please copy paste here the permissions of the target directory ? Also did you try running the cp command after the sodu su - ?

Comment: There is 1 directory bellow the root is called "work" as in the tutorial. But it did not work there as well. But your answer set me to ask the right question. So thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps:

1. Do "sudo su -" It'll give you root permission
2. Go to the directory where you want to save or create the file for example: echo "Hello" > hello.txt

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that this command makes folders only readable:

```
was sudo chmod -R 755 work
```

The following guide [Files: Changing User Permissions in Terminal](http://droppedframe.com/2017/11/07/chmod-why-it-matters-user-permissions-in-os-x/) helps to better specify your needs EX:

```
chmod 707 snails.txt
```

The 707 is called octal notation, and reads from left to right.

- 7 = read/write/execute;
- 6 = read/write;
- 5 = read/execute;
- 4 = read only;
- 0 = no permissions granted.

My solution was:

```
was sudo chmod -R 707 work
```

Comment: Down voted for violating the [principle of least privilege](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege).

Comment: It is an open project. Everyone has a 100% acces for the whole tutorial. 
also I am the only one acces to the server, so I should have full permission. https://www.guru99.com/pyspark-tutorial.html

Comment: Nonetheless, 777 (-rwxrwxrwx) is unnecessarily over permissive.

Comment: what is your recommendation?

Comment: Depends on which user is trying to write the file during the save operation and that users groups. Permissions are “user” “group” and “other”, 777 is “read” “write” and “execute” for the 3. Essentially your user and the notebooks user need the 3, assuming that the notebooks user is not in your users group then i.e. 707 would do it.

Comment: Thank you, I will use that.